# how to work with laravel-chat app in pusher.js if I have no internet connection

Tags: laravel, pusher-js

Lately, my internet connection is going sour and sometimes I get no internet, can I work with like resuming this chat-feature, will I be able to write one without an internet connection

https://blog.pusher.com/how-to-build-a-laravel-chat-app-with-pusher/

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-echo-server which is a self-hosted pusher compatible server.

Comment: Please explain to me what it can do to me sir :)

Comment: Have you read https://www.npmjs.com/package/laravel-echo-server? It's all explained there.